# Make a selection of data based on criteria

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a database in excel and I am trying to make a selection of those data by means of a conditional, the same one that I already have defined, it is the first time that I do this type of thing in python.

```
import pandas as pd

input_data = [[1,  'Col'],
              [2,  'Col'],
              [3,     'Row']]

ExcelPrincipal = pd.ExcelFile('NewData.xlsx')
PW = ExcelPrincipal.parse('Hoja1')  

print('Element',5*' ','Zx_req',7*' ') 
for i in range(len(input_data)):

    if input_data[i][1] == 'Row':
        z_req = 0.00046533157126525757
        print(i+1,12*' ', z_req)

        for i in range(len(PW)):        
            z_comp = z_req - PW.values[i][1]

            if (z_comp*10000) > -0.5 and (z_comp*10000) < 2.5:
#                C = 'Yes'
#            else:
#                C = 'Not'
```

I attach the excel [EXCEL](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AieO48E0rWr2lTRZr0YDA-9a3g6t?e=Is2Z09) so that they can visualize my data, all those that are in 'Yes' I seek to extract them from my database and store them in a list, something like this:

```
Element       Zx_req                       list_selection        
3              0.00046533157126525757       ['6X20', '6X25', '8X15', '8X18', '8X21', '8X24', '8X28', '8X31', '10X15', '10X17', '10X19', '10X22', '10X26']
```

It is precisely this form of extraction that is complicated for me, I would greatly appreciate the help, kind regards.

Comment: would you like to do that only for one z_req value (0.00046533157126525757), or for all / many of them?

Comment: For many of them, but I already have that part automated, what interests me here is how to extract the values that comply with my excel and store them as a list. @Roy2012.

Comment: Could you please explain what's the calculation of z_comp? I mean - what's the formula you use to calculate it?